# Journalism argot: To fact check, fact checking, fact checker

Tags: argot

Comment dit-on “This story ought to be fact-checked” ? etc.

Je voudrais savoir comment les journalistes le disent, dans l'argot des journalistes.

Merci!

Comment: On  aurait du  vérifier les faits de cette histoire

Comment: Je ne suis pas journaliste, mais j'entends à l'occasion: _recouper les sources_.

Answer (score 2):

From *Le Monde*

[Le "fact checking", nouveauté journalistique](http://www.lemonde.fr/technologies/article/2011/09/22/le-fact-checking-nouveaute-journalistique_1575952_651865.html)

> Autre genre appelé à se développer à l'approche de l'élection présidentielle : le *fact checking* (**vérification des faits**) politique, qui consiste à contrôler l'exactitude des affirmations et promesses des hommes politiques.

From Wikipedia, [Vérification par les faits](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9rification_par_les_faits)

Answer (score 2):

Les faits relatés dans cette investigation (ou bien ce reportage) devraient être vérifiés.

Answer (score 0):

Je conseille *[revérification](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9rification_par_les_faits)* (avec bien sûr le verbe *revérifier*), c'est-à-dire vérifier encore une fois les faits à sa disposition.